# Sorting array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am currently have an array of array. I would like to sort it base on the date value inside one of the array. For example,

This is the array I have got,

```
arrayOfArray = [
  ["Date", "01/02/2017", "02/02/2016"],
  ["Temperature", "19", "16"],
  ["Humidity", "80%", "86%"]
]
```

and I would like it to be sorted in this way:

```
newArrayOfArray = [
  ["Date", "02/02/2016", "01/02/2017"],
  ["Temperature", "16", "19"],
  ["Humidity", "86%", 80%"]
]
```

I would like to sort the array base on the date array, latest come first. 
How can i achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: By the way, is this MM/DD/YY or DD/MM/YY?

Comment: @BenM I did try sort(). However, it seems that it is more likely for vertical sorting

Comment: @PatrickRoberts DD/MM/YY

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry if i ask stupid question. However, could you please explain a bit further as i am new to js.

Comment: Your edit clarified why it's not just `sort` on the arrays in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and take a needed array as pattern for sorting and rebuild the array again.

```js
var array = [["Date", "01/02/2017", "02/02/2016"], ["Temperature", "19", "16"], ["Humidity", "80%", "86%"]],
    selected = array[0],
    temp = selected.slice(1).map(function (_, i) { return i + 1; });
    
temp.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getISO(d) { return d.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$2-$1'); }
    return getISO(selected[a]).localeCompare(getISO(selected[b]));
});

temp.unshift(0);
array = array.map(function (a, i) {
    return temp.map(function(index){
       return array[i][index];
    });
})

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Just wondering what if my date format is MM/YYYY only, how do i change the getISO function ?

Comment: just take a part of the replacement function: `function getISO(d) { return d.replace(/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1'); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce it to another array, pushing to it while sorting the values starting from first index.

```js
let arr = [
  ["Date", "01/02/2017", "02/02/2016"],
  ["Temperature", "19", "16"],
  ["Humidity", "80%", "86%"]
];

function getISO(d) {
  return d.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$2-$1');
}
let m = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
  let [n, ...rest] = b;
  if (n === 'Date') {
    rest.sort((x, y) => Date.parse(getISO(x)) - Date.parse(getISO(y)));
  } else {
    rest.sort((x, y) => parseInt(x) - parseInt(y));
  }
  a.push([n, ...rest]);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(m);
```

I took [Nina's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129854/3993662) `getISO` method to make the `Date.parse` work correctly in every environment.

Comment: Thanks mate. Just wondering what if my date format is MM/YYYY only, how do i change the getISO function ?

Comment: `function getISO(d) { return d.replace(/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1'); }` @GaryFan --- might get tricky somewhere though. Maybe add a day manually for safety, like `function getISO(d) { return d.replace(/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-01'); }`

Comment: @GaryFan: Re baao's comment above, you *would* need the day (by adding `-01` as he/she describes).

Answer (score 0):

Your datastructure is not optimal to get sorted. May change it to a *data per date* structure:

```
var dataPerDate = [];
var [dates,temp,humidity] = arrayOfArrays;
dates.forEach((date,i)=>{
  if(!i) return;
  dataPerDate.push({
    date,
    temp:temp[i],
    humidity:humidity[i]
  };
});
```

So now you can sort it easily:

```
dataPerDate.sort(
 (a,b)=>new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that adapts [MDN's recommendation for using `map()` in `sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map):

```js
let arrayOfArrays = [
  ["Date", "01/02/2017", "02/02/2016"],
  ["Temperature", "19", "16"],
  ["Humidity", "80%", "86%"]
]

function sortByDate(outer) {
  const [ [label, ...values], ...rest ] = outer
  const dates = values.map((value, index) => {
    // convert date string to number
    const time = Date.parse(value.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$2-$1'))
    
    // map object to remember original index and value
    return { time, index, value }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time)
  
  // return sorted dates with other subarrays re-ordered dependently
  return [
    [
      label,
      ...dates.map(date => date.value)
    ],
    ...rest.map(([label, ...inner]) => [
      label,
      ...inner.map((value, index) => inner[dates[index].index])
    ])
  ]
}

console.log(sortByDate(arrayOfArrays))
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to consider using an object for the data and writing your own sort-function to sort on the date of this object, like so:

```js
var Datapoint = function (date, temp, humidity) {
  this.date = date;
  this.temp = temp;
  this.humidity = humidity;
};

var array = [
  new Datapoint(new Date(2017, 1, 1), 19, 80),
  new Datapoint(new Date(2016, 1, 2), 16, 86),
  new Datapoint(new Date(2017, 0, 2), 13, 88),
  new Datapoint(new Date(2017, 1, 1), 21, 76)
];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.date > b.date ? 1 : a.date < b.date ? -1 : 0;
});

// Just for representation
Datapoint.prototype.toString = function () {
  var dateString = this.date.getDate() + "/" + (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + this.date.getFullYear();
  return "Date: " + dateString + ", temperature: " + this.temp + "&deg;, humidity: " + this.humidity + "%";
};

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = array[0].toString() + "<br/>" + array[1].toString() + "<br/>" + array[2].toString() + "<br/>" + array[3].toString();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```